# Jasmine test makes no pass/fail report under webdriver.io

Tags: testing, jasmine, webdriver-io

Running the following jasmine test under webdriver.io like this: `node path/to/test/script.js`, the test executes (web browser is pulled up, target page visited), and thanks to the last line, the jasmine 'it' functions (below) do execute (without the last line, they don't, although the 'describe' function still runs).

But jasmine doesn't provide any kind of report result for the 'it' tests and the 'expect' assertions; there's nothing on the console from jasmine.  There's no 'pass/fail' result, and so forth.

How to get jasmine to make a report, and esp. one that is readable by Jenkins?

The problem test script:

```
var webdriverjs = require('foo-bar/node_modules/webdriverio');
var jasmine = require('foo-bar/node_modules/jasmine-node');

var options = {
    port: 4445,
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: process.argv[2] || 'phantomjs'
    }
};

describe('my webdriverjs tests', function () {
  var client;

  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 9999999;

  beforeEach(function() {
    client = webdriverjs.remote(options);
    client.init();
  });

  it('shows the correct title', function (done) {
    client
      .url('http://localhost:4444').getTitle(function(err, title) {
        expect(title).toBe('foo bar');
      }).call( done );
  });

  afterEach(function(done) {
    client.end(done);
  });
});

jasmine.getEnv().execute();
```

Note: Cross-posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriverio/-EOrQ003B9I

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some of the same challenges when I was looking into this. The big issue is that this test needs to be executed as a jasmine test, not a webdriver test.

```
decribe('my webdriverio tests with jasmine', function(){
    var client;

    beforeEach(function(){
        client = require('path/to/webdriverio').remote({
            desiredCapabilities: {browserName:'safari'}
        }).init.url('https://www.stackoverflow');
    }, 5000);

    afterEach(function(done){
        client.end(done);
    }, 5000);

    it('runs a very simple test',function(done){
       client.getTitle(function(err,result){
            expect(result).toBe('Stack Overflow');
       }).call(done);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Now to run this test, you would just run a typical [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) command from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to the naming convention you are using. First, you need to remove the last line: `jasmine.getEnv().execute();` then run the `jasmine-node` command with the `--matchall` flag:

```
jasmine-node --matchall path/to/test/script.js
```

If you named your file `script_spec.js`, then you could run it without the `--matchall` flag.

This is also assuming you have `jasmine-node` installed globally. If you want to use the local `node_modules` dependency, then you need to run this command:

```
./node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node --matchall path/to/test/script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **jasmine-node** module you should run your spec with

`node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node $TEST_DIRECTORY`

And your test should end with *spec.js, *spec.coffee or *spec.litcoffee as [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-node) said.

And `jasmine.getEnv().execute();` and `var jasmine = require('foo-bar/node_modules/jasmine-node');` should not be in your script.